# Javascript time and date change by timezone difference in hours

Tags: javascript, date, time, timezone, timezone-offset

I have this code, which is to change the time and date - according to timezone difference for example `5` hours (indicated by `/////TIME ZONE DIFFERECEN/////`), but it is not working how i would expect it to run; e.g: not changing the date and time when applicable. Can anyone help.

```js
var dateObj = new Date();
var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
var months = ["31"];
if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0)) {
  months.push("29");
} else {
  months.push("28");
}
monthsappend = ["31", "30", "31", "30", "31", "31", "30", "31", "20", "31"];
months.concat(monthsappend);

time = "7:00pm";

var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
var AMPM = time.match(/\s?([AaPp][Mm]?)$/)[1];
var pm = ['P', 'p', 'PM', 'pM', 'pm', 'Pm'];
var am = ['A', 'a', 'AM', 'aM', 'am', 'Am'];
if (pm.indexOf(AMPM) >= 0 && hours < 12) hours = hours + 12;
if (am.indexOf(AMPM) >= 0 && hours == 12) hours = hours - 12;
var sHours = hours.toString();
var sMinutes = minutes.toString();
if (hours < 10) sHours = "0" + sHours;
if (minutes < 10) sMinutes = "0" + sMinutes;
timearr = [sHours, sMinutes];

timearr[0] += 5;
/////////////////////////////// TIME ZONE DIFFERENCE////////////////////////////

if (time.toLowerCase().includes("pm")) {

}
if (timearr < 0) {
  day -= 1;
  if (day == 0) {
    month -= 1;
    if (month == 0) {
      month = 12;
      year = dateObj.getFullYear() - 1;
    }
    day = months[month - 1];
  }
} else {
  if (timearr => 24) {
    timearr[0] = 24 - timearr[0];
    if (day == months[month - 1]) {
      day = 1;
      month += 1;
      if (month == 12) {
        month = 1;
        year += 1;
      }
    }
  }
}

newdate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
console.log(newdate);
console.log(timearr[0]);
```

Comment: In `if (timearr < 0)`, *timearr* is a array so the expression is always false. In `if (timearr => 24)` you're evaluating an arrow function so it's always true. Perhaps you mean `>=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first I'll point out the bugs:

- You have an arrow function `=>` instead of a greater-than-or-equal-to operator `>=`  (Thanks RobG).
- You treat `timearr` as both an array, and later as a single number.  I think you meant to compare `timearr[0]`.
- When you add the 5 hours, you're concatenating strings.  `"19" + 5 === "195"`.  You need to work with numbers here, not strings.
- You forgot to adjust `timearr[0]` in the first section of the large `if` statement.
- You have subtraction in opposite order when you adjust `timearr[0]` in the second section of the large `if`.  (`24 - 26 === -2`, you probably meant `26 - 24 === 2`).
- At the end, you increment `month += 1` before checking `if (month == 12)`.  Either that needs to be in an else, or you'd have to check for `month === 13`.
- You're using `==` in places where `===` would be more appropriate.
- You forgot `var` when you declared `timearr`.
- You took the current date, but hard-coded the time.

Overall, it looks like you are trying to output the current date, in day/month/year format, at UTC+5.  There are many simpler ways to do what you're asking.  For example:

```
// Get the current moment in time, as a Date object.
var d = new Date();

// Add 5 hours of absolute duration.  The setter handles the bubbling for you.
// Be sure to use UTC here, to avoid interference from transitions of the local time zone.
d.setUTCHours(d.getUTCHours() + 5);

// Get the properties we want to display.
var year = d.getUTCFullYear();
var month = d.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var day = d.getUTCDate();

// Construct the string for output in the desired format.
var s = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
```

Or with [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com):

```
var s = moment().utcOffset(5).format('D/M/YYYY');
```

Do keep in mind also "Time Zone != Offset".  It just so happens that all the places in the world that currently use `UTC+5` use it year-round (ex, Pakistan) but if you were talking about US Eastern Time, it would be `UTC-5` for some parts of the year, and `UTC-4` for other parts of the year.

Comment: Re "*to avoid interference from transitions of the local time zone*". There is always the conundrum of whether the user wants a 6 hour duration, or to see a 6 hour time difference.  ;-)

Comment: @RobG  I believe he wants UTC+5 in this case, so it shouldn't matter if the local time zone is EST, IST, or whatever - you'd be moving only along UTC lines.  But yes - I'm making that assumption.  Also - I should point out that since we shifted the point in time to account for offset, any use of local time from here forward is theoretically flawed.  "Epoch Shifting" like this only works with UTC.